# Display value from column B if column A is NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am wondering how i can display data from column B if Column A is null. The reason is if we get a product from one of our manufactures it is put in a different column. However, when i go to build the report the two columns essentially the same thing and it is throwing the graph way off. Any help would be appreciated.

Something like this maybe?

```
Case When column A isnull then column B?
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`ISNULL()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) or [`COALESCE()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx), or [`CASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

```
SELECT    ISNULL(ColumnA, ColumnB) AS [YourColumn]
FROM      FOO
```

OR

```
SELECT    COALESCE(ColumnA, ColumnB) AS [YourColumn]
FROM      FOO
```

OR

```
SELECT    CASE WHEN ColumnA IS NULL THEN
              ColumnB
          ELSE
              ColumnA
          END AS [YourColumn]
FROM      FOO
```